# Замена string на char

Tags: c++, строки

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: можно ли как-то преобразовать следующий код с использованием `string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str[3] = { "Anna", "Max", "Dan" };
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        cout << str[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

на код с использованием `char`?
Я знаю, что `char` разделяет слово на символы, поэтому не уверен, что такое возможно. Прошу Вас помочь мне разобраться!

Comment: Напишите const char* вместо string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы написали, не компилируется, и даже непонятно, что вы хотите.

Если вы хотите вывести все три имени, то это делается так:

```
int main()
{
    string str[3] = { "Anna", "Max", "Dan" };
    for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++) {
        cout << str[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Чтобы сделать это же без `string`, делайте точно так же:

```
int main()
{
    const char * str[3] = { "Anna", "Max", "Dan" };
    for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++) {
        cout << str[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Можно еще сделать имена изменяемыми, собрав массив строк, а не константных указателей:

```
int main()
{
    char str[][5] = { "Anna", "Max", "Dan" };
    for (int i = 0; i < size(str); i++) {
        cout << str[i] << " ";
    }
}
```